# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.profiles.active' in value "gc-${spring.profiles.active}"

Tags: axon

I'm getting below error when trying to run https://github.com/fransvanbuul/webinar-20181213/tree/master/giftcard. This code is using `Spring Boot + AxonIQ`.

```
2018-12-13 22:34:25.071 ERROR 12228 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.profiles.active' in value "gc-${spring.profiles.active}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:172) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:237) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:211) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveNestedPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:88) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:62) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:539) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer.getApplicationId(ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer.java:68) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer.getContextId(ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer.java:64) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer.initialize(ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer.java:53) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:649) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:373) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at com.example.giftcard.GiftcardApplication.main(GiftcardApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
```

Comment: It looks like a placeholder in your application.properties. Try running the jar with commandline argument --spring.profiles.active=something

Comment: Yes, you have to activate one Spring profile. Or you can edit `application.properties` and have them all active `spring.profiles.active=command,query,client`

Comment: Even the read me is updated now. All details are present.